# How to make Glimpse for Json.NET work for Web API requests?

Tags: c#, json.net, glimpse

I've installed Glimpse for Json.NET (1.0.2) in the hope to see more information in the JSON tab as advertised [here](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/06/06/json-net-5-0-release-6-glimpse-plugin). And this seems to work well with MVC requests however the JSON tab is empty for Web API request.

Since I have a couple of custom formatters and model binders, I've tried to disable those but it still wouldn't help.

I'm not even sure if this feature is supposed to work.